# Using Output From json2ts.com in Angular 2.x

Tags: angular, typescript

http://json2ts.com/ generates output with a wrapper like `declare module namespace` and I'm not sure how to use/reference/import that within my Angular 2.x application.

As an example, if I provide this JSON:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Bob",
   "Position": [
       {"Title" : "Manager"}
],
}]
```

It will generate this output:

```
declare module namespace {

    export interface Position {
        Title: string;
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        Position: Position[];
    }

}
```

It appears it's typing to namespace these objects which is something I'd like to use. I'm already running into cases where objects within an object have the same name as other objects and there ends up being conflicts.  But so far I can't figure out how to import this into a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output produced by http://json2ts.com/ does not produce an external module you can import. It also creates namespaces using an improper construct that has been deprecated for over a year. If you want to use it, you would not `import` at all but instead reference `namespace` as a global variable.

Personally, I would avoid using this tool.

Comment: That explains why I've been having trouble using it.  The way I have been using it is to delete the `declare module namespace {` wrapper, change each interface to a class, and then import them into components like I would any other export class.  There is no better way to auto-generate classes out of JSON?

Comment: There's a vs code plug-in that lets you paste JSON as an interface. I think removing the wrapper is the right approach but I would caution you against replacing `interface` with `class`